# Json response with a variable value

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

[image]

Hi, I am trying to get a message to say the value of the data's user id as in line 95. However, the json message isnt recognizing it as a variable and is just printing that line how it is. I am unfamiliar with the syntax here, could somebody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code (or other text) please. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: You need to use template strings:  (``)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include variables in text strings using JavaScript, you will have to delimit the string with backticks.  This character: `

```
`user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully`
```

The single quote / apostrophe you're using now does not allow for inclusion of variables.